# Binomial expansion of $(1+X)^b$ of the form $\sum\limits_k b^kf_k(X)$ with $f_k(X)$ polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

For each $b \in \mathbb{N}, (1+X)^b=\sum\limits_{n=0}^b{{b}\choose {n}}X^{n}$ is a polynomial function of $X$. How to write $(1+X)^b$ in terms of $b$ as a closed expression of the form $$(1+X)^b=\sum\limits_kb^kf_k(X)$$ where each $f_k(X)$ is a polynomial function of $X$?

Comment: It seems natural to write the function under the form $\exp(b\ln(1+X))$ and thus $\sum_k b^k\ln^k(1+X)/k!$.

Comment: However, $ln^k(1+X)$ does not look like a polynomial to me...
Regarding the question, you should put $f_k(X) = {b \choose k}X^k/b^k$. If that is of any help is another question entirely, but at least it is a polynomial in $X$. :)

Comment: The function $(1+X)^b$ does not belong to $\mathbb Z[X,b]$ hence one cannot write it as a sum $\sum\limits_kb^kf_k(X)$ for finitely many functions $f_k(X)$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

Comment: I do not mean $f_k(X)$ to be a polynomial function over $\mathbb{Z} $. It will have factorial terms in the denominators.

Comment: Actually the comment of Paul Enta solves my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there exist polynomials $f_k (X)$ such that for each $b \in \mathbb{N}$, you have $$(1+X)^b = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} b^k f_k (X) \, . $$

The LHS is a polynomial with degree $b$, so if you take $b+1$ derivatives with respect to $X$ you get $0$. Doing the same on the RHS tells you that the polynomials $f_k (X)$ are all of degree at most $b$. Since this is true for all $b$, all the $f_k(X)$ are constant. So the RHS doesn't depend on $X$, which is of course absurd.

Conclusion : there are no such polynomials.